# ajax if statement not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, if-statement

hi i have some ajax coding in which the if condition is not at all working, whenever the program executes else statement only works even the program satisfies the if statement.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CheckDetails()
    {
        var http = false;

        if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
            http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } else {
            http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }

        var rid = document.new_booking.ph_number.value;

        http.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (http.readyState == 4) {
                var str_d = http.responseText;
                if (str_d == "no") {
                    document.getElementById('cus_name').focus();
                } else {
                    var str_details = http.responseText;
                    var arr_details = str_details.split("~");
                    document.new_booking.cus_name.value = arr_details[0];
                    document.new_booking.pick_aline1.value = arr_details[1];
                    document.new_booking.pick_aline2.value = arr_details[2];
                    document.new_booking.pick_area.value = arr_details[3];
                    document.new_booking.pick_pincode.value = arr_details[4];
                    document.new_booking.drop_aline1.focus();
                }
            }
        }
        http.open("GET", "ajax.php?evnt=det&rid=" + rid);
        http.send();
    }
</script>
```

and its ajax.php file is given below

```
<?php
    if ($_GET['evnt'] == 'det') {
        $rid = $_GET['rid'];
        include("configure.php");
        $select = mysql_query("select * from new_booking where ph_number = '$rid'");
        $count = mysql_num_rows($select);
        if ($count > 0) {
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($select);
            echo $row['cus_name']
                . "~" . $row['pick_aline1']
                . "~" . $row['pick_aline2']
                . "~" . $row['pick_area']
                . "~" . $row['pick_pincode']
                . "~" . $row['drop_aline1']
                . "~" . $row['drop_aline2']
                . "~" . $row['drop_area']
                . "~" . $row['drop_pincode'];
        } else {
            echo "no";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Log what you think `str_d` is right before the `if`, is it the right result?

Comment: And I had *almost* forgotten what AJAX looked like before jQuery...

Comment: @Der Flatulator It's a good idea to know what AJAX is. jQuery just makes it look prettier.

Comment: @RPM it also makes ajax requests robust and cross-browser compliant

Comment: Alert the value of str_d and see what you get

Comment: The problem is in your server code, you should really check what response you're getting from the request. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/eqEDm/) that shows you that the javascript is "fine".

Answer (score 1):

You can open your page with Chrome (or Chromium) and then debug your javascript code using builtin debugger (Ctrl+Shift+I, "Console" tab). I guess you will see some JS errors there.

Basically, your code works OK (at least when I removed all database access from it, since I don't have your DB).

If you don't like Chrome, use Firefox and FireBug extension. On 'Network' page you can see that your ajax request was executed (or not executed).

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, I would say that some whitespace is sneaking into your AJAX response somewhere. Because `"no "` isn't equal to `"no"`, it is always hitting your `else` branch.

You might consider sending back a whitespace-agnostic value. You could rewrite the whole mess to use JSON, which would require a lot less work on both ends:

```
// PHP:
if ($_GET['evnt'] == 'det') {
    $rid = $_GET['rid'];
    include("configure.php");
    $select = mysql_query("select * from new_booking where ph_number = '$rid'");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($select);
    if ($count > 0) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($select);
        // YOU PROBABLY WANT TO WHITELIST WHAT YOU PASS TO JSON_ENCODE
        echo json_encode($row);
    } else {
        echo json_encode([ "error" => "no" ]);
    }
}

// js:
http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (http.readyState == 4) {
        var str_d;
        try {
            str_d = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
        } catch(e) {
            str_d = false;
        }

        if (str_d && str_d.error === "no") {
            document.getElementById('cus_name').focus();
        } else {

            document.new_booking.cus_name.value = str_d.pick_aline1;
            document.new_booking.pick_aline1.value = str_d.pick_aline2;
            document.new_booking.pick_aline2.value = str_d.pick_area;
            // etc...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried this but i am getting lots of error and i am new to ajax so i dont know how to fix

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problem. This worked for me.

```
if (str_d.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '') == "no")
```